# Toggle Switch question

Tags: switches

I've searched around but cannot find an answer on this.   Does anyone manufacture toggle switches that connect like the diagram below?   (up: connects 1 & 2,  middle connects 3 & 4,  down connects 5 & 6).  I need a switch that will supply two different loads (one when up,  one when down),  but also be able to ground a pin on a board when in the middle position. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Type "dip switch" into google.

Comment: 3PST describes it, though that could lead to one that switches all 3 poles at the same time.

Comment: what is the load voltage and current?

Comment: 2 DC solenoids.      12V ,   1 Amp.

Comment: Please describe your goal with a little more information. You may search with a complicated solution that could be answered with a simpler approach.

Comment: It is not a toggle, it is sliding switch.

Comment: here's the simple version of what I was trying to describe (sorry,  I'm not an engineer).   I was hoping for a (on) on (on) toggle switch that would connect how the original diagram showed.   There is a load out on the board that I need to feed to one of two coils, but only one can be on at a time.    The board has an enable pin that disables the board when that pin is grounded,  if it's left open the board is on.    So the middle position in the diagram below would need Gnd feeding into position 3 and out position 4 when the toggle was in it's middle position.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Wz55FSq

Answer (score 2):

You need a 6 terminal, 3 position, ON - ON - ON toggle switch.

[image]